# Creating a Temp Table and populating Data Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a Temp Table and populate data for a basic report

Create Statement

```
Create temporary table attendance_report(first_name varchar(40), weeks_present integer, weeks_away integer, total_weeks integer)
```

I get a table with a column with no name at the start - So 5 in total instead of 4.

Then to populate I have the following:

```
INSERT INTO attendance_report (first_name, weeks_present, weeks_away, total_weeks)
Select first_name from members
Where id = 19
Union
Select Count(*) from Rolls join Rollmappings
on Rolls.roll_id = rollmappings.id
Where rolls.member_id = 19
and rollmappings.roll_year = '2023'
and status != 'A'
Union
Select Count(*) from Rolls join Rollmappings
on Rolls.roll_id = rollmappings.id
Where rolls.member_id = 19
and rollmappings.roll_year = '2023'
and status = 'A'
Union
Select Count(*) from Rolls join Rollmappings
on Rolls.roll_id = rollmappings.id
Where rolls.member_id = 19
and rollmappings.roll_year = '2023'
```

I receive the following:
Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: is it just me or i can't find the values keyword? and is that `union` so that they are become several rows instead of column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INSERT...SELECT...` statement makes no sense. The insert lists 4 columns - `(first_name, weeks_present, weeks_away, total_weeks)` but your UNION only outputs 1 column. Your column names are confusing. The PK for `members` appears to be `id`, but your `Rolls` table has a column named `roll_id`, which I would expect to be called just `id`, if consistent with `members`.

Based on what can be inferred from your current query, it should probably be:

```sql
INSERT INTO attendance_report
    (first_name, weeks_present, weeks_away, total_weeks)
SELECT m.first_name, SUM(r.status <> 'A'), SUM(r.status = 'A'), COUNT(*)
FROM members m
JOIN rolls r ON m.id = r.member_id
JOIN rollmappings rm ON r.roll_id = rm.id
WHERE rm.roll_year = 2023
AND m.id = 19 /* comment out this criterion to retrieve for all members */
GROUP BY m.id;
```

If the above query is not what you are looking for, please update your question with DDL (`SHOW CREATE TABLE members;`) and sample data ([markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables)) for your `members`, `Rolls` and `Rollmappings` tables, and the desired result.